# Is there a way to look up live delay information for Eurostars?

Tags: uk, trains, online-resources, high-speed-rail, delays

I'm currently on a Eurostar that's stationary somewhere in Kent... No announcements, no staff to be seen, but excellent 4G signal strength! And I'd quite like to know how late we're likely to be, some I can let people meeting me know.

Is there a website somewhere I can use to lookup live Eurostar / Eurotunnel delay / timing information?

(I'm aware of going to the [Eurostar website then Travel Information then Live Departures & Arrivals](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-information/service-information), but that claims my train is on time, when the sitting stationary in Kent suggests otherwise.... Perhaps something like the [OpenTrainTimes live maps, eg ECML part 2](http://www.opentraintimes.com/maps/signalling/ECM2) or [RealTimeTrains](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk), both of which generally seem very accurate for train location+delays for UK trains)

Comment: You should be on RealTimeTrains, go for "St Pancras International to Thames Tunnel".  (e.g. http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/L11028/2015/08/04/advanced )

Comment: It now shows the notice: `Please be aware that there may be some delays of up to one hour due to an earlier incident.`  On the Eurostar page; and many of the currently en route trains show delays on the Arrivals page.

Comment: @nkjt Wow, didn't realise that Real Time Trains had coverage on HS1! That looks like at least half of what I was after for an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some delays, the [Eurostar Live Service Information page](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-information/service-information/rtti#/dep/7015400/7015400) will list the delay for the service, and estimated revised arrival times. However, that doesn't always get updated as often as you might like...

For Eurostars still in the UK, it's possible to stalk them with quite some accuracy on [RealTimeTrains.co.uk](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/). If you search for departures from [St Pancras International](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/search/basic/STP), find your Eurostar, then pick *More details*, you can get a display [like this one for a train in September 2015](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/L11093/2015/09/15/advanced) showing delays at 20-odd monitoring points on the way to the tunnel, eg

[image: Screenshot of Real Time Trains]

For Eurostars in France, you can't get that level of timing information WRT actual vs planned, at least as far as I'm aware. What you can do is follow the train's realtime position on the [SNCF Geo-Localisation interface](https://www.sncf.com/fr/itineraire-reservation/geolocalisation) (zoom in on northern France), eg

[image: SNCF realtime location]

That will at least give you a rough guide of delays, eg if your train is supposed to be in Brussels in 5 minutes and is showing as somewhere near Calais, you'll know it's quite late...

I'm not aware of any similar realtime train-stalking systems for Belgium, nor for in the Channel Tunnel itself. For those situations, you can try asking the staff in the Buffet (coaches 6 and 13), who can look things up if they're not too busy.

Comment: Link to *SNCF Geo-Localisation interface* gives Error 404.

Answer (score 5):

You can look on the Twitter feed [Eurostar Delays](https://twitter.com/search?q=eurostar%20delays&src=tyah), which is feeding announcements from staff and passengers alike.  Here's a snapshot...

[image]

The 'generic' [Twitter feed for Eurostar](https://twitter.com/search?q=eurostar&src=tyah) has some info, but it refers more to press and media reports rather than real-time info...

[image]

And for additional information, the [Eurostar's site for Disruption Compensation](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/service-information/disruption-compensation) has details about how to make a claim.