# Do I have to worry about delays in international trains? (UK, Belgium, Germany)

Tags: uk, trains, public-transport, belgium, scotland

I am German and would like to take the train from Stuttgart to Glasgow in August. A flight would be shorter, but I want to take care of the environment and enjoy the landscape a little, not everything has to be fast. Unfortunately I will have to book from different websites and different providers.  (Deutsche Bahn GmBH, Eurostar, whatever travels between London and Glasgow) From my experience in Germany I know that trains are sometimes simply cancelled and nobody is interested in how someone gets home.

Does anyone have experience with international trains? What happens if they are cancelled? I don't feel like getting stuck in London because the train from Glasgow is cancelled. In Germany it would be a minor problem because I always get from A to B here somehow, but I don't want to experience it abroad.

Comment: I don't know what that's like in general, but for me there are Scotland and England. That is why I have classified these trains as "International".

Comment: Do you really need to book separately? If you book the whole thing as a single ticket you’ll get the international rail guarantee which lets you board the next available train if you are delayed. But the whole trip is probably a bit too long to do in a single day (shortest itinerary is over 13 hours).

Comment: I think so, the only website that can even calculate a trip which I found is interrail. Do you have any recommendations for a website to book this on? The 13 hours don't really matter, I love travelling, it is already holiday for me. I found good trips where I start at 5am in Stuttgart and arrive in Glasgow at 8pm. The thing is like I said if the trains are reliable.

Comment: @NuTa Scotland to England is a domestic journey: both are in the UK. It's no different from traveling between states in Germany or the US.

Comment: @NuTa I'm guessing from your starting point that you're in/around Stuttgart, or at least somewhere in Germany - have you tried at the nearest DB ticket office? bahn.de won't let you book online, but it will find the whole schedule and seems to suggest you should be able to purchase the ticket from them either over the phone or in person.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't think about that possibility. Everything is online these days.. :D Also I didn't even consider the DB page since the company has pretty bad reputation here in Germany, seems like the website is good, it has all options I see, thank you again!

Comment: @Nu Ta London to Scotland travel can be interrupted at times by ongoing maintenance work on the line. This particularly happens at weekends and public holidays and means you’d have to endure a bus replacement service for the affected part of the journey. You should check for planned engineering works before you book http://m.nationalrail.co.uk/pj/disruption/planned/8/7/2019

Comment: There should be ways of getting CIV fares but they seem to be somewhat broken right now. I will need to look this up a bit more. Hopefully I can write an answer soon :)

Comment: I booked it through the DB Reisezentrum here in Stuttgart. It was much more expensive than I thought but I have the guarantee to not be stranded anywhere on the way. Thank you everybody for your help. I will love to visit Scotland.

Comment: It would be really odd if DB couldn't or wouldn't sell you a ticket from Stuttgart to Glasgow. When I try, I can book the ticket online, but there are no print-at-home tickets available, so they will send you a paper ticket by regular mail.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately delays and cancellations are not uncommon. You have a bunch of options here.

It seems like www.trainline.com will allow you to book this. You still have to split it into two tickets: Stuttgart to London and London to Glasgow but it's with a single operator and so you will be rebooked for free on the next available train if you miss your connection.

Trainline also honors delays from certain income providers including the German ICEs. 
https://faq.trainline.eu/article/449-miss-train

Otherwise I would book this as multiple flex tickets.

Overall this will be pricey. A third options would be to simply fly and buy some carbon offsets to mitigate the environmental impact.

Comment: Before booking this as multiple Flex tickets, I would ask at a "DB Reisezentrum" how much the trip is. They have more booking possibilities at the counter. Also, there are specialized travel agencies for rail travel, whom the OP might give a call.

Comment: Trainline cannot honor delays, as they do not operate any trains...

Comment: You don't need to operate trains to have appropriate arrangements in place as Trainline does.

Comment: Trainline don't list UK rail companies apart from Eurostar in the URL you give, so if the OP is late into London they won't be covered for the London->Glasgow leg.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this itinerary can and should be done on two tickets.  One Stuttgart-London ([from ~€60](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/angebot/sparpreis-europa/london-spezial.shtml)) and one London-Glasgow (from ~£50).

The Stuttgart-London leg will be guaranteed - so any delays will allow you to take the next train.

Assuming you get an "Advance" ticket on the London-Glasgow train (that limits you to a specific train), then as per [Missed connection](https://www.railfuture.org.uk/When+things+go+wrong)  even if the connecting Eurostar was delayed you will be allowed to travel on the next available train. (If you get an Anytime or Off peak ticket then you will be able to board any train in any case.)

**Edit:** addressing Owain's point

With a CIV ticket from London-Glasgow, you would be legally covered to be able to continue your journey in the event of any delays.  [These tickets are hard to get.](https://www.seat61.com/UKconnections.htm#Option%203)  However, despite this, and similarly to the "Split ticket" scenario described in the link I posted above, the UK train operators are very unlikely to prevent you travelling on a later train if a well planned connection is missed due to another late running train service (including Eurostar).

See also:

- [Delayed Eurostar arrival in London, going to miss my connection, what to do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57864/delayed-eurostar-arrival-in-london-going-to-miss-my-connection-what-to-do)
- https://www.railforums.co.uk/threads/missed-connection-due-to-late-runnig-eurostar-query.117260/

> [With an advance ticket,] once the journey has begun. If the passenger is delayed and the rail industry [...] is at fault, [...], change to another train of the same company is allowed to get them to their destination with the least delay. This is irrespective of combinations of rail tickets held.

Comment: This is incorrect, as it only applies to a missed connection because of a delayed UK train. A delayed international train will NOT be covered, unless the ticket is from/to LONDON INTL (CIV). This gives CIV (Convention Internationale pour le transport des Voyageurs) protection and through ticket status to the international journey. See https://www.seat61.com/UKconnections.htm#Option%203

Comment: @Owain.  As per your link, even without a CIV ticket Eurostar "normally" allow you on the next train.  In my experience, and as per the link I provided, although there is no legal entitlement the train operators in the UK will normally allow you to travel if another train service has been delayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you book this on one ticket you are in a good situation. The railways must get you to your destination, and must take care of you.

But even if you are not on one tickets there are certain rights you have.
DB and Eurostar are both members of Railteam, and as such if you miss your connection in Brussel of Paris because the ICE was late Eurostar will put you on the next train with free seats. It is important however that in that case that you get an endorsement on your ticket from the ICE conductor.
(That is a good reason to print out your ticket, and not rely on an app).

You could book this in two sections: Stuttgart - Paris with DB, and Paris - Glasgow with Eurostar (select UK as country)